# Проверить данные из файла, для каждой строки питон

Tags: python, файлы

Может кто-нибудь и подскажет, дан файл txt. 10000 строк. В строке содержится информация об имени, электронной почте и возрасте человека. Нужно проверить данные из файла, для каждой строки:

1. Присутствуют все три поля,
2. поле имени содержит только буквы,
3. поле email содержит `@` и `.`,
4. поле возраст является числом от 10 до 99.

Пример файла:

> ```
> Ли cgft@ya.ru 58  
> Волочкова tgnrnmo@mail.ru 9  
> Ольга fffrdfc@ya.ru 58  
> Чонгкун ykiuh@mail.ru 84   
> iflyyvp.ru 73  
> Чонгкун sibft@ya.ru  
> Ярослав42 ffcbzhygtt@gmail.com 74  
> Ли  25 Dgiga mwwtk.mail.ru 95  
> Тролль65 hrihukodr@ya.ru 31  
> Ольга zc@gmail.com 99  
> Яочуан xi@mail.ru 100   
> snaper fdpqj@gmail.com 16  
> Зефир jqwpvljxg@mail.ru 7  
> Хенг  xvupuy@mail.ru 108  
> Халк mihpuy@mail.ru
> ```

и тд.......

Я в начале сделала: каждую строку вогнала в список(код прикрепляю):

```
with open('registrations.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        print( line.strip().split())
```

> ```
> ['Джигурда', 'roueomxq@ya.ru', '14']  
> ['Ли' , 'cgft@ya.ru' , '58']  
> ['Волочкова' , 'tgnrnmo@mail.ru' , '9']  
> ['Ли' , '25']
> ```

и тд.....

Но дальше не могу понять, как прогонять данные? Понимаю, что можно сделать через классы? Но как? Не могу сориентироваться

Comment: Это можно одной регуляркой сделать

Comment: Бьешь файл по строкам, идешь циклом по каждой строке и проверяешь регулярным выражением

Comment: в задаче не сказано, что ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО отсутстввать будут последние элементы. То есть если вместо трех полей скажем, присутствует одно.
Это поле рассматривать как имя? как возраст? как "мыло"?
или вообще не рассматривать такую строку? Ее удалять?  Считать количество удаленных строк?
Вообще - что должно быть результатом выполнения программы?

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 5):

Весь смысл этого кода в том, что каждая строка проверяется регулярным выражением, и если `re.match` возвращает `None` т.е. не находит совпадение то функция возвращает `False`

```
import re

file = 'Ли cgft@ya.ru 58\nВолочкова tgnrnmo@mail.ru 49\nОльга fffrdfc@ya.ru 58'

pattern = '\s*[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]+\s+[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+(?:\.[\w]+)+\s+[1-9][0-9]\s*$'

def is_valid(file):
    for line in file.splitlines():
        if not re.match(pattern, line): return False
    return True

print(is_valid(file))
```

Comment: Только вот есть один недостаток у данного паттерна. Он примет возраст 00 верным (т.е. строка Ли cgft@ya.ru 00 окажется для него верной)

Comment: @MazZz3R Спасибо, исправил

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!

Answer (score 1):

100% будет работать вот на такой простыне. В качестве приятного бонуса, код сформирует два .txt файла с логами, где будут плохие и хорошие строки:)

```
class NotNameError(Exception):
    pass

class NotEmailError(Exception):
    pass

def check(line):
    name, mail, age = line.split(' ')
    symbols = ('@', '.')
    age = int(age)
    if name.isalpha() is False:
        raise NotNameError
    elif age not in range(10,100):
        raise ValueError()
    else:
        for char in symbols:
            if char not in mail:
                raise NotEmailError
    return line

with open('registrations_.txt', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as ff:
    for line in ff:
        line = line[:-1]
        try:
            string = check(line)
        except NotNameError:
            bad = open ('registration_bad.log', mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
            bad.write(line + 'Имя содержит цифры' + '\n')
            bad.close()
        except NotEmailError:
            bad = open ('registration_bad.log', mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
            bad.write(line + 'Некорректно указан E-mail' + '\n')
            bad.close()
        except ValueError:
            bad = open ('registration_bad.log', mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
            bad.write(line + 'Неверные данные' + '\n')
            bad.close()
        else:
            good = open('registraton_good.log', mode='a', encoding='utf-8')
            good.write(line + '\n')
            good.close()

ff.close()
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!